# how to make a growing line animation on canvas android

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to make an animation of growing line it will look like that line is moving towards the end of canvas width and the start of the line will be constant only end of line should be growing
here is my code of the class which paint line on android PLZ HELP ANY HELP WOULD BE APPREICATED.

```
 package com.example.line;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
 import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
 import android.view.View;

 public class MyPlay extends View{

 float startx = 30;
 float starty = 60;
 float endx=0;
 float endy=0;
 public MyPlay(Context context) {
     super(context);
     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setARGB(50, 254, 10, 50);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    textPaint.setTextSize(20);
    canvas.drawText("Made by Skyrush", canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, textPaint);

    Paint linePaint = new Paint();
    linePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    linePaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

    //canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy, linePaint);
    if(endx < canvas.getWidth()){

        endx = startx+5;
        endy = starty-5;
        canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy, linePaint);
        invalidate();
    }
    invalidate();
 }
}
```

Comment: So did I understand correctly ; you have two points p0=(x0, y0) and p1=(x1, y1), and you want to have line grow from p0 to p1? If so, doing some research on _linear interpolation_ would be much help.

Comment: i have two points p0=(x0,y0) and p1=(x1,y1) and i want a line from p0 to p1 then grow forward at some rate like p1(x1+5,y1+5) till it reaches canvas width.

Comment: does somebody know how to get the desired output please help as i am learning right now through making simple animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this](https://smdaudhilbe.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/how-to-animate-line-gradually-growing-from-starting-point-to-ending-point/) webpage there's a way to make an animation of a line growing.

You just have to implement the following methods in a custom view:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    //  starting point
    x1 = 50;
    y1 = 50;

    //  ending point
    x2 = getWidth() / 2 + getWidth() / 4;
    y2 = getHeight() / 2 + getHeight() / 4;

    Log.d("line xy xy", x1 + " : "+y1+" : "+x2 + " : "+y2);

    divideLineIntoEqualParts();
}


//  dividing line into 50 equal parts
private void divideLineIntoEqualParts() {

/*
 * Courtesy : www.dummies.com
 * (x,y) = (x1 + k(x2 - x1),y1 + k(y2 - y1))
 * */

    listOfPoints.clear();
    for (int k = 1; k <= 50; k++) {
        listOfPoints.add(new PointF(x1 + ((k * (x2 - x1)) / 50),y1 + (k * (y2 - y1)) / 50));            
    }

    Log.d("listOfPoints : size : ",listOfPoints.size()+"");
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(inte < listOfPoints.size()){
        canvas.drawLine(listOfPoints.get(0).x, listOfPoints.get(0).y, listOfPoints.get(inte).x,listOfPoints.get(inte).y, paint);
        inte++;

    if(inte < listOfPoints.size()){
        invalidate();
    }   
}
```